# How to disable .cshtml submit button after submit/click?

Tags: asp.net, razor

Trying to find a good way to disable this save/submit button after it has been clicked once. Here is the code i currently have :

```
<button data-bind="enable: !$root.isSaving(), click: $root.addNewCard.bind($data, $root)" class="primary button" role="button" data-size="sm" onclick="this.disabled = true;" UseSubmitBehavior="false">Save</button>
```

Comment: It looks like your code can disable the button when click it.So what you want to change?

Comment: Just wanting to verify that what i have is a good method of doing that. Disabling the button after one click?

Comment: Yes,it's a good and simple method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous method i had above worked out well!